# What does "TOTAL ON" when used on a joined SELECT statement with parentheses actually do?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm currently learning SQL on Oracle and one of the examples that are given in my module is rather baffling, mainly because no explanation of it is actually given. I'm sure it's fairly basic but it uses the keywords "TOTAL ON" as part of it and I don't really know what this means or what is actually happening with this join.

I tried searching for a solution but understandably, using the word "TOTAL" brings up stuff on the SUM aggregate function.

Here is the statement:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.*, TotalPurchased
FROM CUSTOMER
JOIN
    (
        SELECT CustomerID, SUM(PurchasedAmount) AS TotalPurchased
        FROM PURCHASE
        GROUP BY CustomerID;
    ) TOTAL ON TOTAL.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID;
```

Can anyone please just tell me what this is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just an alias assigned to a derived table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOTAL` is an alias for the sub-query, `ON` is the start of the clause that specifies the conditions by which the tables are joined.

You could rewrite your query as:

```sql
SELECT table_alias.*,
       subquery_alias.TotalPurchased
FROM   CUSTOMER table_alias
       JOIN (
         SELECT CustomerID, SUM(PurchasedAmount) AS TotalPurchased
         FROM PURCHASE
         GROUP BY CustomerID -- No ; here.
      ) subquery_alias
      ON subquery_alias.CustomerID = table_alias.CustomerID;
```

---

> I guess the alias then is needed in order to have a name by which to join that subquery?

The alias helps to clarify which column belongs to which table but, in Oracle, it is not required if the columns are unique.

*Note: Some RDBMS require that every sub-query has an alias; Oracle, however, does not.*

For example:

```sql
SELECT dual.*,
       id
FROM   DUAL
       JOIN ( SELECT DUMMY AS id FROM DUAL )
       ON id = dummy;
```

Outputs:

> | DUMMY | ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | X | X |

As it is unambiguous which table contains which column.

But using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
       JOIN DUAL
       ON dummy = dummy;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
       JOIN (SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL)
       ON dummy = dummy;
```

Both raise the exception:

> ```
> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
> ```

As the `ON` clause cannot distinguish which table/sub-query the `dummy` column refers to as the same identifier is used in both.

In either case you can fix the exception by giving the sub-query an alias (and maybe the table an alias) and then prefixing the column identifier with the table-name or the alias to clarify which is which.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c388c2b31fa957534195bd0c1cc53aec)*

Comment: I guess the alias then is needed in order to have a name by which to join that subquery?

Comment: @Tyler See my update for an answer to that.

Comment: Was there a reason that you put the alias `id` for the `DUMMY` column?

Comment: @Tyler To demonstrate that you do not need to use an alias on the sub-query if the columns in the tables/sub-queries are unique. If I had not used an alias there then there would have been a column name `DUMMY` on both sides of the join.

Answer (score 0):

`TOTAL` is just an alias for the nested table within the parenthesis. Maybe it would make more sense reformatted a bit:

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMER.*, TotalPurchased
FROM CUSTOMER
JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerID, SUM(PurchasedAmount) AS TotalPurchased
    FROM PURCHASE
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) AS TOTAL 
  ON TOTAL.CustomerID = CUSTOMER.CustomerID
```

Comment: `AS` before a table/subquery alias is invalid syntax in Oracle. (It is valid before a column alias).

Comment: Interesting. That seems like a weird restriction. I've not seen it with other SQL implementations. The more you learn!

Comment: According to the ANSI/ISO standard `AS` before a table/subquery alias is optional and most RDBMS allow it to be present; Oracle does not and raises syntax errors if it is present.

Comment: There are a lot of pretty finicky differences between Oracle and other DBMSs. I think that's why I'm being taught on it. It seems objectively more difficult than MySQL or SQL Server. In a lot of cases it seems like getting the syntax right on Oracle can make it fairly portable to the other two, but not vice-versa. Case in point, Oracle requires explicit GROUP BY statements which are portable to MySQL, but not really needed.